# Output data with php to csv not inbetween quotes but straight [field]=data

Tags: php, arrays, magento2, php-5.6

I am looking to output data in csv with no quotes.
At the moment I have the values inbetween quotes. I need them straight with no quotes for the standard magento2 import "additional_attributes".

EDIT: I need to mention that I only need the values inside this array without quotes. The rest needs the quotes as they are by default.
So I have multiple columns with quotes and I have that one column called `additional_attributes` that has multiple information in it but needs the values without quotes.

I define the `additional_attributes` in a separate array and print it then to the csv like this:

```
     $additional_attributes = [
        'product_code'       => $article->getArticleCode(),
        'alcohol_gradiation' => trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '',        $article->getAlcohol())), 
    ];


   fputcsv($csvFile, $row, $delimiter);
        $additional_attributes = implode(',', array_map(
        function ($v, $k) {
            return sprintf("%s='%s'", $k, $v);
        },
        $additional_attributes, array_keys($additional_attributes)
    ));

   $row['additional_attributes'] = $additional_attributes;
```

I get the `additional_attribute` values all inbetween `''` like this column bellow. It starts correct in double quotes but then the values should be with no quotes.

My output for the column `additional_attribute` is this (double quotes at the beginning and end are required):

> "product_code='2586',product_code_1='1A25861',product_code_2='N12-25860',alcohol_gradiation='13.50',allergy_warning='2586',evolution='2586',grape_variety='Merlot'"

I need this:

> "product_code=2586,product_code_1=1A25861,product_code_2=N12-25860,alcohol_gradiation=13.50,allergy_warning=2586,evolution=2586,grape_variety=Merlot"

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process it yourself by looping through the array and creating a string with all of the content linked together (just remove the trailing `,` when adding it)...

```
$addAttributes = '';
foreach ( $additional_attributes as $name => $attribute )    {
    $addAttributes .= $name."=".$attribute.",";
}
$row['additional_attributes'] = rtrim($addAttributes,",");
```

If your existing code is...

```
$additional_attributes = implode(',', array_map( function ($v, $k) { 
                   return sprintf("%s='%s'", $k, $v); 
               }, 
               $additional_attributes, 
               array_keys($additional_attributes) ));
```

then you just need to change the `sprintf` as the quotes are in there...

```
return sprintf("%s=%s", $k, $v);
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid answer. Please all together. I don't understand how to fill the data.

Comment: Down I already got:       

  $additional_attributes = implode(',', array_map(
            function ($v, $k) {
                return sprintf("%s='%s'", $k, $v);
            },
            $additional_attributes, array_keys($additional_attributes)
        ));

Comment: You just need to remove the quotes in the `sprintf` - added to answer.

Comment: That new code should be part of the question as it is an important part of the code.